# ionic cache nothing or clear cache each day

Tags: ionic-framework

I have deployed an ionic app as an web app on a server. Whenever I deploy any new changes in ionic part, my users keep using whatever is cached (i.e. older javascripts) and this kills the intended new functionality. I have to ask them to manually clear the cache so that they can use the app with latest changes.

Why does this happen? Is there any way that each day cache is removed? Is it a browser related issue or Ionic issue?

I already have set `cache: false` for my routes like following:

```
  .state('tab.plan', {
    url: '/plan',
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-plan.html',
        controller: 'planCtrl'
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
  .state('tab.simon', {
    url: '/plan/8', 
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/simon.html',
        controller: 'simonCtrl',
        data: {
          css: '/css/simon.css'
        }  
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
```